# Flutter: How to change the view of my NavigationRail without clicking on the icons?

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-provider

I use a classic **NavigationRail**, inside a **Row()** divided in two, to change the view. But I would also like to change the view by clicking on items displayed in the view.
For example, at the beginning **ShowTables()** is visible, and when I click on buttons built by **ShowTables()**, I want to replace **ShowTables()** by an other widget. This new widget could have the possibility to return to **ShowTables()**, keeping the value of my Map **Tables** (or at least my app state **data** if not possible). How can I do ?

```
class NavBarTest extends StatefulWidget {
  final Metadata? data;

  const NavBarTest({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NavBarTest> createState() => _NavBarTestState();
}

class _NavBarTestState extends State<NavBarTest> {
  Map tables = {};
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    /*
      here I init tables...
    */
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child:
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                    NavigationRail(
                      groupAlignment: -1.0,
                      selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
                      leading:
                      Column(children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          child: Image.asset("assets/logo.png"),
                        ),
                      ],),
                      onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedIndex = index;
                        });
                      },
                      labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.none,
                      destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
                        NavigationRailDestination(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.spoke_rounded,color: icon),
                          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.spoke_rounded,color: Colors.yellow),
                          label: Text('First'),
                        ),
                        NavigationRailDestination(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.show_chart_sharp,color: icon),
                          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.show_chart_sharp,color: Colors.yellow),
                          label: Text('Second'),
                        ),
                        NavigationRailDestination(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.info_sharp,color: icon),
                          selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.info_outline,color: Colors.yellow),
                          label: Text('Third'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    // This is the main content.
                    Expanded(
                        child: buildPage(_selectedIndex)
                    )
                  ],
                )
              )
      );
  }

  Widget buildPage(index){
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return ShowTables(tables: tables);
      case 1:
        return const Details();
      case 2:
        return Links(tables: tables);
      default:
        return ShowTables(tables: tables);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: It is changing view, can you explain a little more. Are you trying replace `ShowTables`  with new widget, except those  are included on `switch` case?

Comment: Yes I want to replace with new widget except those are included on switch case

Comment: `click on buttons built by ShowTables()` does it mean there is a button that will be responsible to change the view?

Comment: yes ShowTables() displays many shapes containing a table name (from a database) and when I click on one name, I need to see some informations about the table, so call a widget like Informations(name: nameOfTheTable). After, I also need to return to the previous page (with all the shapes), without reloading my data, which comes from an API. I think I need Provider, but it's not clear in my head